# Why can't I initialize an array with np.zeros and then change elements to arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

In my code I do

```
weights = np.zeros(len(layer_sizes)-1)

for i in range(len(layer_sizes)-1):

    weights[i] = np.random.rand(layer_sizes[i], layer_sizes[i+1])
```

which yields error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

If I just make weights an arbitrary array explicitly, the code runs.

The objective of this code is to create an array of random matrices with given dimension.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, the `np.array` is merely used as an container of matrix of different size. You can just use Python's list, instead of `numpy`.

```
weights = []

for i in range(len(layer_sizes)-1):
    weights.append(np.random.rand(layer_sizes[i], layer_sizes[i+1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run

```
weights = np.zeros(len(layer_sizes)-1)
```

you explicitly create a vector that can only contain `len(layer_sizes)` numbers (scalars).

When you then run:

```
np.random.rand(layer_sizes[i], layer_sizes[i+1])
```

that code generates a matrix of random numbers, which does not fit in a position of a vector that can only hold a single number (the vector can contain multiple numbers, every position in the vector can only contain a single number).

When you say that it works if you just make weights an arbitrary array explicitly, I assume you're using a python list. A list can contain anything (it can also contain a full matrix in every position), so that explains why the code works.

See some of the other answers for what you probably should do instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you definitely want an array container you'd have to use `dtype` `object` (otherwise I'd second @liliscent):

```
>>> layer_sizes = np.arange(3)
>>> weights = np.empty(len(layer_sizes)-1, dtype=object)
>>> for i in range(len(layer_sizes)-1):
...     weights[i] = np.random.rand(layer_sizes[i], layer_sizes[i+1])
... 
>>> weights
array([array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=float64),
       array([[ 0.93504612,  0.35105107]])], dtype=object)
```

Note that I out of habit used `empty` instead of `zeros` since initializatiion isn't necessary in terms of program logic. (For arrays with `dtype` `object` it doesn't make a difference, because they have to be initialized in any case because their elements are ref counted.)

Comment: I prefer to use `np.empty` with object dtype, since it fills it with `None`.  Often that makes more sense than a 0 or 1 fill.